# Gurobi's optimal solution violates constraint by 0.29%

Tags: gurobi, cvxpy

We are solving a large-scale MIQCQP problem:

```
Variables: 7.3K (= 3.7K as continuous + 3.6K as interger)
Objective: Linear
Constraints: 14.8K Linear Constraints + 1 Quadratic Constraint (Q matrix size = 3.7K * 3.7K)
Framework: Cvxpy (version: 1.1.13)
Solver: Gurobi (version: 9.0.3)
```

Gurobi finished optimization and returns the optimal solutions well, but those optimal variables violates the quadratic constraint by 0.014 (in percentage, its 0.29%).

Note: The violation is higher then default [feasibility tolerance](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/feasibilitytol.html) (=1e-6) of Gurobi.

Comment: The inequality you see (cvxpy code) and the inequality gurobi sees (cvxpy-transformed problem) is not necessarily the same -> it's hard to compare *your* amount of constraint-deviation from *gurobis*. There will always be a chance of error-accumulation through this pipeline.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on or.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on or.stackexchange.com